# What is a generic way of finding out whether the kernel has ext4 (or other) bugs?

Tags: linux, ext4, bugs

From /. found this worrisome [post](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/10/23/690) by Theodore Ts'o. Turns out ext4 has some journalling problems. How can I quickly find out version numbers of susceptible kernels for this **and other** bugs?

Comment: You mean like `uname -sr`?

Comment: @htor : no, this I already know. Seriously :) Would be grateful for any resource that can be scraped/processed to provide a bug->version table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can track (and submit) kernel bugs in the [Kernel Bug Tracker](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/) .